# There exist a holomorphic function on the unit disc . True/false

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following statement true/fase

> There  exist  a  holomorphic   function  on the  unit disc  $\mathbb{D}$  such that   $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \begin{cases}  \frac{1}{n} , \text{ n is  even} \\ \frac{1}{n+1}  , \text{n is odd} \end{cases}$

**My attempt** : I think **No**  .

Take  $g(z) = 1/n$ and  $p(z)=  \frac{1}{n+1}$

Now by using identity theorem  we have

$\lim g(z) =\lim p(z) $   but $ g(z) \neq p(z) $  this leads to a contradiction

Am i right ?

Comment: okay @AndreasBlass here $z=\frac{1}{n} $. This is a contradiction with Identity theorem.

Comment: actually you need to take $g(z)=z, p(z)=z/(z+1)$ and note that $f$ must be equal to either by taking subsequences $z=1/n$ for $n$ odd and even respectively

Comment: If $z=1/n$ and if, as in the statement of the question, $n$ is an integer (so that""even" and "odd" make sense) then your $g$ and $p$ are defined only at some isolated points and therefore are not holomorphic. So I don't see what you could apply the identity theorem to.

Comment: I've deleted my first comment. My objections to the proof in the question were correct, but the "Furthermore" sentence at the end was not. The comment by @Conrad is correct except for a typo: $p(z)$ should be $1/(z+1)$

Comment: @AndreasBlass but $p(1/n) = \frac{n}{n+1} \neq  \frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: @Andreas I think that $z/(z+1)$ is what sends $1/n$ to $1/(n+1)$ as $1/(z+1)$ doesn't have the right limit at zero

Comment: @Conrad Yes, you’re right

Comment: @Conrad You're right; I need to go to sleep before I write any more silly things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sequence $\langle\frac{1}{n}\rangle$ has limit $0\in D$. Plugging $1/n=z$ gives $f(z)=z$ and $\frac{z}{z+1}$ in the neighborhood of $0$. By Identity theorem $f(z)=z$ and $f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$ simultaneously on whole of $D$ (a contradiction)

Comment: \langle, \rangle for $\langle, \rangle$

Comment: @David P.....thanks!